# Creating an array with "For" loop

Tags: procedural-programming

I need to perform a number of operations within a `For` loop and store the results in an indexed array (without using the Append function)
For examole (to make it simple), I need to find the square of numbers i = 1 to 5 and sore it in y[i].
In precedural languages it would look like:

```
   for i = 1,5,i++,
        y(i)=i^2
    end
```

To implement this in *Mathematica* I tried this code:

```
 For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++,
    y[[i]] = i^2;  
    ]
```

which failed. Is there a way to create such array (y)?

Comment: Do you understand why it failed? `y` is not defined, so you can't access `y[[i]]`. Try defining `y` before and it works (for that, see e.g. `ConstantArray`). **Edit** My comment assumes, as you state, that you _need to use `For`_. Otherwise that's much simpler with `Table`.

Comment: [You almost never need a `For[]` loop.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609) Try `y = Range[5]^2`.

Comment: Or lookup [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.The problem is that I am using images and applying many functions (filtering, image processing, etc..) and then storing the final result in an array for comparison. To me, the simplest way would be to use a For loop and run the full code repeatedly on each image.

Comment: Then you should look up `Map[]` or `Table[]` as already suggested, if you have a list of images. If you really must loop, use `Do[]` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. (I'm new to Mathemetica!)

Comment: If OP is doing image processing OP should probably be using at least some of Mathematica's image processing functions: `Blur`, a whole host of `Filters`, *etc*.

Answer (score 1):

```
y = Range[5]; (* y needs to be predefined as anderstood pointed out *)
For[ i = 1, i <= 5, i++,
  (* body *)
  y[[i]] = i^2
]
```

If it has to be `For`...

```
y
(* {1, 4, 9, 16, 25} *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @HebaSea You are welcome. Be sure to look up the alternatives given in the comments above. `For` really is no fit for Mathematica.